# Rails: How do I handle automatically upgrading a user account once a limit is reached?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, stripe-payments

I have a rails app which stores files, in which a user can subscribe to three plans:

- plan 1: *free trial* up to **50 files** for **30 days**
- plan 2: up to **250 files**
- plan 3: up to **500 files**

How would I go about automatically upgrading/downgrading the user plans when:

- The 30 day trial ends or user uploads more than 50 files
- File limit is exceeded and goes into another bracket
- Or a file is deleted and the user **goes down** a level

How do I set the Rails app to "Watch" a user account for these changes?

Is there a better way than sticking logic in the Files controller create and delete actions?
And what about the 30 day trial logic?
Thank you!

Note: I can handle the actual switching of the subscriptions just fine, just looking for logic to monitor and trigger the switches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup [association callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) on the user's Plan. Assuming you have a has_many relationship to Plan, in User.rb you could have something like

```
has_many :plans, :through => :user_plans,
  :after_add => :check_plan_eligibility,
  :after_remove => :check_plan_eligibility
```

and then

```
protected
def check_plan_eligibility(obj)
  # Do checks here based on your rules, and update the user's plan ID accordingly
end
```

Comment: Jnunn, the relationship is a has_one.. how would your answer change? I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Observers (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Observer.html)

or

ActiveRecord::Callbacks (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)

30 day trial could be checked upon user login. The rest could be done using callbacks when the user updates.